# What were the proportions of state militias in Continental Army?

Tags: united-states, military, american-revolution

[The wikipedia article on the Continental Army](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Army) suggests that "The army never numbered more than 17,000 men." but also lists a number of 80,000 as the peak size.  The former number refers specifically to those enlisted for the federal army.  Presumably the latter number includes the state militias, giving a value of about 63,000 state vs 17,000 federal, but this logic seems a bit tenuous.

What were the proportions of the Continental Army federal enlisted troops to state militia?  Preferably with reliable sources.

Comment: 'the Continental Army size was actually 100,000, not counting the militia. “Probably twice that number soldiered as militiamen, for the most part defending the home front, functioning as a police force, and occasionally engaging in enemy surveillance” in addition to supplementing the Continental Army for stretches.' from https://observer.com/2017/07/soldiers-militia-american-revolution/  and another good source with a breakdown of the conn. militia units is here - https://allthingsliberty.com/2016/07/connecticut-militia-1739-1783/  using that information you can extrapolate for the whole USA.